# how to redraw linearlayout after clicking on button in android?

Tags: android

I have a linearlayout that is filled with texviews dynamically when i click on a button , but the content of linearlayout doesn't appear, how can i redraw it ??

Comment: Post some code, sounds like you're doing things wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force a view to draw, call invalidate(). (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the textView is changes inside the on click listen event on the button then there is no need to call the invalidate. I suggest you to post the code so that it will give a more clear picture.